# Using a regular dll with shared mfc dll

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc, shared-libraries

I have a regular dll with shared mfc dll. it was built on vc++ 6.0. I want to use it in vc++ 2008 windows form application.it has a header file, a lib and a dll.
I am adding some lines of the said header files

```
   #ifdef   DLLBUILD
   #define  DLLFUNC   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI
   #else
   #define  DLLFUNC   extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) WINAPI
   #endif 

   DLLFUNC int SC06StepInit(void)
```

When I add this header it shows multiple errors of same type

> error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';'
>   error
>   C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int

error start from line `DLLFUNC int SC06StepInit(void)` to all lines started with the same name `DLLFUNC`. I have no idea of starting any function with a name than return type and than again a name.

The source code of this dll also had all the functions in the same manner.

I want to know. What is this way of defining a function is called and to use such libraries.

Comment: Try `int DLLFUNC ...` - change the order. I'm pretty sure the type must precede the calling convention.

Comment: This dll is in use of some programs and working well. I am not the developer of this dll. I want to use it.  I want to know what is this format and how to use it

Comment: You are "adding some lines" to the header files, and you are getting compiler errors pointing precisely to the lines you have added. Which is a good indication that those lines are syntactically incorrect, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#ifdef   DLLBUILD
#define  DLLFUNC   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define  DLLFUNC   extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif 

DLLFUNC int SC06StepInit(void);
```

You are trying too much in a macro:

- extern "C"
- DLL import/export attribute
- `WINAPI` specification

Limit it. Find out how you should export the function, and who the client of your DLL are.

Comment: Let me make something clear. Peoples who had responded to my question might have an idea that I am developing a dll but this is not the case. I am the client of this library and unable to use it because of such syntax which is new to me.

Comment: If you are the client, the ask who has developed the DLL and gave you such header. If they didn't give you header, you can use Dependency Walker to find how the *functions look*